# Trying to build an SQL query (MySQL) that counts the number of bookings of each facility, for each month of the year

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having a pickle with a query. I am trying to create a google chart line-graph, that shows the amount of bookings for each activity over the course of a year. In the pictures below I have it in weeks, but I don't much care if it is in months or weeks.

How I want to approach this query is by counting the total bookings of a specific facility, one week at a time.

**These are the 2 tables I am working with for this query.**
[image]

**To produce this :**

[image]

**So that I can use the result of this query to produce a google-chart that will resemble this :**

[image]

### **RESOLVED. Query Answer is :**

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(b.booking_date, '%Y-%m') AS booking_month,
         SUM(f.facility_name = 'Pitch 1')    AS Pitch1,
         SUM(f.facility_name = 'Pitch 2')    AS Pitch2,
         SUM(f.facility_name = 'Training Pitch 1')  AS TPitch1,
         SUM(f.facility_name = 'Training Pitch 2')  AS TPitch2,
         SUM(f.facility_name = 'Front Bar') AS FrontBar,
         SUM(f.facility_name = 'Back Bar') AS BackBar,
         SUM(f.facility_name = 'Gaelscoil Building 1') AS Gaelscoil1,
         SUM(f.facility_name = 'Gaelscoil Building 2')  AS Gaelscoil2
         FROM tbl_booking b
         INNER JOIN tbl_facility f ON f.facility_id = b.facility_id
         GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(b.booking_date, '%Y-%m')
         ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(b.booking_date, '%Y-%m')
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some kind of pivoting. In SQL, a standard way to do it is to use *conditional aggregation*. Please note that this requires you to know in advance how many columns your query will return (ie you need to know the list of facilities *before* running the query).

Consider:

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(b.booking_time_start, '%Y-%m') AS booking_month,
    SUM(f.facility_name = 'Pitch1')    AS Pitch1,
    SUM(f.facility_name = 'Pitch2')    AS Pitch2,
    SUM(f.facility_name = 'T.Pitch1')  AS TPitch1,
    SUM(f.facility_name = 'T.Pitch2')  AS TPitch2,
    SUM(f.facility_name = 'front Bar') AS FrontBar,
    SUM(f.facility_name = 'Back Bar')  AS BackBar
FROM tbl_booking b
INNER JOIN tbl_facility f ON f.facility_id = b.facility_id
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(b.booking_time_start, '%Y-%m')
ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(b.booking_time_start, '%Y-%m')
```

NB: I added the year to the first column, that represents the aggregation period ; this avoids mixing data when you have more than one year of data, and also allows proper sorting.

Comment: Had to make some very minor adjustments to your date section, but beyond that your query was perfect. Thank you for your great help. (Query added to edit.)